# Missing files when build from unity3d to IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a unity project to IOS but I am always getting a red missing file called "libiconv.2.dylib".
I tried building different projects but its always the same file missing.
I also tried some of the solutions i found here in stackoverflow but nothing worked ( adding the plugin as Embedded binary, changing the target ios version from 8 to 9)

PS: XCode version 9.4, Unity3d 2018.2.4f1

**Update:** When i tried to build an empty unity project i got 201 errors.

```
Showing Recent Errors Only
  "il2cpp::vm::Runtime::AlwaysRaiseExecutionEngineException(MethodInfo const*)", referenced from:
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_0(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_1(Il2CppObject*, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_2(Il2CppObject*, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_3(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_4(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_5(Il2CppObject*, short, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      UnresolvedVirtualCall_6(Il2CppObject*, int, MethodInfo const*) in UnresolvedVirtualCallStubs.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::vm::Class::FromIl2CppType(Il2CppType const*)", referenced from:
      RuntimeInvoker_Boolean_t97287965_RuntimeObject(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      RuntimeInvoker_Boolean_t97287965_RuntimeObject_RuntimeObject(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      RuntimeInvoker_Int32_t2950945753(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      RuntimeInvoker_Int32_t2950945753_RuntimeObject(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      RuntimeInvoker_Boolean_t97287965_RuntimeObject_RuntimeObject_ObjectU5BU5DU26_t712384779(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      RuntimeInvoker_Int32_t2950945753_RuntimeObject_ObjectU5BU5DU26_t712384779(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      RuntimeInvoker_Boolean_t97287965_RuntimeObject_RuntimeObject_SByte_t1669577662(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) in Il2CppInvokerTable.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::vm::String::NewWrapper(char const*)", referenced from:
      g_mscorlib_Assembly_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      _Attribute_t122494719_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      IEnumerator_t1853284238_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      IEnumerable_t1941168011_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      String_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      String_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator_String_Split_m3580120853(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      Enum_t4135868527_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator_Enum_ToString_m3124963174(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::String::InternalSplit(Il2CppString*, Il2CppArray*, int, int)", referenced from:
      _String_Split_m2077324731 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
      _String_InternalSplit_m1398300789 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
      _String_Split_m3580120853 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Security::SecurityFrame::_GetSecurityStack(int)", referenced from:
      _SecurityFrame__GetSecurityStack_m449275820 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
      _SecurityFrame_GetStack_m347707425 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Security::Principal::WindowsIdentity::GetCurrentToken()", referenced from:
      _WindowsIdentity_GetCurrentToken_m841791956 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
      _SecurityContext_Capture_m1047743382 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Security::Cryptography::RNGCryptoServiceProvider::RngClose(long)", referenced from:

      _RNGCryptoServiceProvider_RngClose_m3915778345 in Bulk_mscorlib_8.o

      _RNGCryptoServiceProvider_Finalize_m1304072372 in Bulk_mscorlib_8.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Security::Cryptography::RNGCryptoServiceProvider::RngOpen()", referenced from:
      _RNGCryptoServiceProvider__cctor_m3587754670 in Bulk_mscorlib_8.o
      _RNGCryptoServiceProvider_RngOpen_m792795472 in Bulk_mscorlib_8.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::Remoting::RemotingServices::GetVirtualMethod(Il2CppReflectionType*, Il2CppReflectionMethod*)", referenced from:
      _RemotingServices_InternalExecuteMessage_m311230144 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
      _MethodCall_ResolveMethod_m326183261 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
      _RemotingServices_GetVirtualMethod_m3786317812 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::Remoting::RemotingServices::InternalExecute(Il2CppReflectionMethod*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppArray*, Il2CppArray**)", referenced from:
      _RemotingServices_InternalExecuteMessage_m311230144 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
      _RemotingServices_InternalExecute_m1851601664 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::copy_from_unmanaged(long, int, Il2CppArray*, int)", referenced from:
      _Marshal_copy_from_unmanaged_m2834266824 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _Marshal_Copy_m1222846562 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _Marshal_Copy_m1714210296 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::GetTarget(int)", referenced from:
      _GCHandle_get_Target_m1824973883 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _GCHandle_GetTarget_m1711976502 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::CompilerServices::RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(Il2CppArray*, long)", referenced from:
      _RuntimeHelpers_InitializeArray_m4077124945 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _RuntimeHelpers_InitializeArray_m3117905507 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoMethod::get_IsGenericMethodDefinition(Il2CppReflectionMethod*)", referenced from:
      _MonoMethod_get_IsGenericMethodDefinition_m3024870835 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o


  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoMethod::GetGenericArguments(Il2CppReflectionMethod*)", referenced from:
      _MonoMethod_GetGenericArguments_m4278548385 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoMethod::GetDllImportAttribute(long)", referenced from:
      _MonoMethod_GetDllImportAttribute_m853324018 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoMethod_GetPseudoCustomAttributes_m3959384572 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::Remoting::Activation::ActivationServices::EnableProxyActivation(Il2CppReflectionType*, bool)", referenced from:
      _ActivationServices_EnableProxyActivation_m1823951881 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
      _RemotingConfiguration_RegisterActivatedClientType_m4212089575 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
      _RemotingConfiguration_RegisterWellKnownClientType_m1237674062 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoField::SetValueInternal(Il2CppReflectionField*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:
      _MonoField_SetValueInternal_m2352116743 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoField_SetValue_m2338106905 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoField::GetValueInternal(Il2CppReflectionField*, Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:
      _MonoField_GetValueInternal_m532651562 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoField_GetValue_m3124733531 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::Remoting::Proxies::RealProxy::InternalGetProxyType(Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:
      _RealProxy_InternalGetProxyType_m2154819545 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
      _RealProxy_GetProxiedType_m130698758 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoField::GetFieldOffset(Il2CppReflectionField*)", referenced from:
      _MonoField_GetFieldOffset_m3808764875 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoField::GetParentType(Il2CppReflectionField*, bool)", referenced from:
      _MonoField_GetParentType_m2478933781 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoField_get_ReflectedType_m471710812 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoField_get_DeclaringType_m2066594735 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoMethod::get_name(Il2CppReflectionMethod*)", referenced from:
      _MonoCMethod_get_Name_m3090866252 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoMethod_get_name_m2690633670 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MonoMethod_get_Name_m3372146751 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::ModuleBuilder::getMethodToken(Il2CppReflectionModuleBuilder*, Il2CppReflectionMethod*, Il2CppArray*)", referenced from:
      _ModuleBuilder_getMethodToken_m454517975 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _ModuleBuilder_GetToken_m1735168917 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::TypeBuilder::create_runtime_class(Il2CppReflectionTypeBuilder*, Il2CppReflectionTypeBuilder*)", referenced from:
      _TypeBuilder_CreateType_m3375483507 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _TypeBuilder_create_runtime_class_m2581270900 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::MethodBuilder::MakeGenericMethod(Il2CppReflectionMethod*, Il2CppArray*)", referenced from:
      _MethodBuilder_MakeGenericMethod_m2175748754 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::DynamicMethod::destroy_dynamic_method(Il2CppReflectionDynamicMethod*, Il2CppReflectionDynamicMethod*)", referenced from:
      _DynamicMethod_destroy_dynamic_method_m2651031212 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _DynamicMethod_Finalize_m3410343626 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::DynamicMethod::create_dynamic_method(Il2CppReflectionDynamicMethod*, Il2CppReflectionDynamicMethod*)", referenced from:
      _DynamicMethod_create_dynamic_method_m1579875961 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _DynamicMethod_CreateDynMethod_m3853278069 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::ModuleBuilder::RegisterToken(Il2CppReflectionModuleBuilder*, Il2CppObject*, int)", referenced from:
      _ConstructorBuilder__ctor_m1580993362 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _ModuleBuilder_RegisterToken_m4166846047 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _MethodBuilder__ctor_m3664913099 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::ModuleBuilder::set_wrappers_type(Il2CppReflectionModuleBuilder*, Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:
      _ModuleBuilder__ctor_m164976504 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _ModuleBuilder_set_wrappers_type_m2998401134 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Text::Encoding::InternalCodePage(int*)", referenced from:
      _Encoding_get_Default_m1632902165 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
      _Encoding_InternalCodePage_m4154357846 in Bulk_mscorlib_9.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::AssemblyBuilder::basic_init(mscorlib_System_Reflection_Emit_AssemblyBuilder*)", referenced from:
      _AssemblyBuilder__ctor_m3936521321 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _AssemblyBuilder_basic_init_m1526438565 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::GetTargetHandle(Il2CppObject*, int, int)", referenced from:
      _GCHandle__ctor_m2690474163_AdjustorThunk in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _GCHandle_GetTargetHandle_m423901123 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _GCHandle_Alloc_m3823409740 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Assembly::load_with_partial_name(Il2CppString*, mscorlib_System_Security_Policy_Evidence*)", referenced from:
      _Assembly_load_with_partial_name_m2517830235 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _Assembly_LoadWithPartialName_m3378291794 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Assembly::FillName(Il2CppReflectionAssembly*, mscorlib_System_Reflection_AssemblyName*)", referenced from:
      _Assembly_FillName_m1660001542 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _Assembly_UnprotectedGetName_m600830855 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Assembly::InternalGetType(Il2CppReflectionAssembly*, mscorlib_System_Reflection_Module*, Il2CppString*, bool, bool)", referenced from:
      _Assembly_GetType_m3468564723 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _Assembly_InternalGetType_m3065345470 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Assembly::GetTypes(Il2CppReflectionAssembly*, bool)", referenced from:
      _Assembly_GetTypes_m1724781913 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Assembly::GetManifestResourceInternal(Il2CppReflectionAssembly*, Il2CppString*, int*, Il2CppReflectionModule**)", referenced from:
      _Assembly_GetManifestResourceInternal_m1224391897 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoType::get_Module(Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:
      _MonoType_get_Module_m2397868165 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::Remoting::Proxies::RealProxy::InternalGetTransparentProxy(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppString*)", referenced from:
      _RealProxy_InternalGetTransparentProxy_m1765012608 in Bulk_mscorlib_6.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoType::IsByRefImpl(Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:
      _MonoType_IsByRefImpl_m2022486753 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Assembly::get_location(Il2CppReflectionAssembly*)", referenced from:
      _Assembly_get_location_m3128831763 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _Assembly_get_Location_m3857174850 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoType::GetConstructors_internal(Il2CppReflectionType*, int, Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:
      _MonoType_GetConstructors_internal_m2316633399 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoType_GetConstructors_m2574682189 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoEnumInfo::get_enum_info(Il2CppReflectionType*, Il2CppEnumInfo*)", referenced from:
      _MonoEnumInfo_get_enum_info_m1661176095 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoEnumInfo_GetInfo_m1670492558 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoCustomAttrs::IsDefinedInternal(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:
      _MonoCustomAttrs_IsDefined_m2996012389 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoCustomAttrs_IsDefinedInternal_m2193933235 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::FreeHandle(int)", referenced from:
      _GCHandle_Free_m1457699368_AdjustorThunk in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _GCHandle_Free_m1457699368 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _GCHandle_FreeHandle_m2765220421 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Object::GetType(Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:
      _MonoCustomAttrs_IsUserCattrProvider_m2878058089 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _Object_GetType_m88164663 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoCustomAttrs_GetPseudoCustomAttributes_m765345333 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoCustomAttrs_GetCustomAttributes_m1347331976 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoCustomAttrs_IsDefined_m2996012389 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MulticastDelegate_CombineImpl_m2857239134 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _Object_ToString_m1740002499 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::TypeBuilder::create_generic_class(Il2CppReflectionTypeBuilder*)", referenced from:
      _TypeBuilder_CreateType_m3375483507 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _TypeBuilder_create_generic_class_m3823884980 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::get_DirectorySeparatorChar()", referenced from:
      _MonoIO_get_DirectorySeparatorChar_m820086465 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Path__cctor_m3273994011 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::get_ConsoleInput()", referenced from:
      _MonoIO_get_ConsoleInput_m610865495 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoType::GetPropertiesByName(Il2CppReflectionType*, Il2CppString*, unsigned int, bool, Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:
      _MonoType_GetPropertiesByName_m2491778142 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoType_GetPropertyImpl_m1327032087 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o
      _MonoType_InvokeMember_m2156385067 in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::get_ConsoleOutput()", referenced from:
      _MonoIO_get_ConsoleOutput_m1601613425 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::Close(long, int*)", referenced from:
      _FileStream_Dispose_m2599766137 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_Close_m3406045462 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::Write(long, Il2CppArray*, int, int, int*)", referenced from:
      _FileStream_WriteInternal_m4028396817 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_Write_m3999708352 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _FileStream_FlushBuffer_m914568182 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::GetLength(long, int*)", referenced from:
      _FileStream_get_Length_m426703983 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_GetLength_m2300093603 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::Open(Il2CppString*, int, int, int, int, int*)", referenced from:
      _FileStream__ctor_m3151488352 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_Open_m2245605962 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o


  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::GetFileType(long, int*)", referenced from:
      _FileStream__ctor_m3087090334 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_GetFileType_m101289143 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _FileStream__ctor_m3151488352 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::RemapPath(Il2CppString*, Il2CppString**)", referenced from:
      _MonoIO_RemapPath_m1142466502 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Path_InsecureGetFullPath_m129101154 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::DeleteFile(Il2CppString*, int*)", referenced from:
      _File_Delete_m321251800 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_DeleteFile_m3839141322 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::IO::MonoIO::CreateDirectory(Il2CppString*, int*)", referenced from:
      _Directory_CreateDirectoriesInternal_m3735342319 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _MonoIO_CreateDirectory_m120522531 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::RegionInfo::construct_internal_region_from_name(Il2CppRegionInfo*, Il2CppString*)", referenced from:
      _RegionInfo_GetByTerritory_m2536737365 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _RegionInfo__ctor_m1348635004 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _RegionInfo_construct_internal_region_from_name_m1315402456 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::Emit::ModuleBuilder::create_modified_type(Il2CppReflectionTypeBuilder*, Il2CppString*)", referenced from:
      _ModuleBuilder_create_modified_type_m3780542108 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o
      _ModuleBuilder_GetType_m813933439 in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CultureInfo::construct_datetime_format(Il2CppCultureInfo*)", referenced from:
      _CultureInfo_get_DateTimeFormat_m1982351742 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_construct_datetime_format_m1928121315 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CultureInfo::construct_internal_locale_from_current_locale(Il2CppCultureInfo*)", referenced from:
      _CultureInfo_ConstructInternalLocaleFromCurrentLocale_m3684789125 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_construct_internal_locale_from_current_locale_m2484355412 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CultureInfo::construct_internal_locale_from_name(Il2CppCultureInfo*, Il2CppString*)", referenced from:
      _CultureInfo_ConstructInternalLocaleFromName_m4012802696 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_construct_internal_locale_from_name_m3254739477 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CompareInfo::assign_sortkey(void*, Il2CppSortKey*, Il2CppString*, il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CompareOptions)", referenced from:
      _CompareInfo_assign_sortkey_m2100240770 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CompareInfo_GetSortKey_m1915852346 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CompareInfo::internal_compare(mscorlib_System_Globalization_CompareInfo*, Il2CppString*, int, int, Il2CppString*, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _CompareInfo_internal_compare_m2522722857 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CompareInfo_internal_compare_switch_m1882891666 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CultureInfo::construct_internal_locale_from_lcid(Il2CppCultureInfo*, int)", referenced from:
      _CompareInfo__ctor_m1655607648 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_get_IcuName_m2258611679 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo__ctor_m385185322 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_ConstructInternalLocaleFromLcid_m2304903600 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_get_Parent_m672689885 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_Construct_m1572693873 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_get_TextInfo_m2342840448 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CompareInfo::construct_compareinfo(mscorlib_System_Globalization_CompareInfo*, Il2CppString*)", referenced from:
      _CompareInfo__ctor_m1655607648 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CompareInfo_construct_compareinfo_m509660150 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CompareInfo_System_Runtime_Serialization_IDeserializationCallback_OnDeserialization_m734465833 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o


  "il2cpp::vm::Reflection::GetTypeObject(Il2CppType const*)", referenced from:
      Attribute_t861562559_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      _Attribute_t122494719_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      Type_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      MemberInfo_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      _MemberInfo_t3922476713_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      _Type_t3588564251_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      Exception_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::GC::SuppressFinalize(Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:
      _GC_SuppressFinalize_m1177400158 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _FileStream_Dispose_m2599766137 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Environment::GetMachineConfigPath()", referenced from:
      _Environment_GetMachineConfigPath_m43519138 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Globalization::CultureInfo::construct_number_format(Il2CppCultureInfo*)", referenced from:
      _CultureInfo_get_NumberFormat_m1244033732 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CultureInfo_construct_number_format_m3346478783 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Environment::internalGetEnvironmentVariable(Il2CppString*)", referenced from:
      _Environment_internalGetEnvironmentVariable_m3668851860 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_m394552009 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Environment_InternalGetFolderPath_m468390978 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Environment_ReadXdgUserDir_m2654856189 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _CompareInfo__cctor_m1837489679 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o


  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Environment::get_Platform()", referenced from:
      _Environment_get_Platform_m520224871 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Environment_get_OSVersion_m961136977 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Environment_GetFolderPath_m327623990 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Environment_get_IsRunningOnWindows_m1804804030 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _DirectoryInfo_Initialize_m1389772934 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Path_GetInvalidPathChars_m3959874485 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Path_InsecureGetFullPath_m129101154 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      ...

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Environment::get_SocketSecurityEnabled()", referenced from:
      _Environment_get_SocketSecurityEnabled_m190813817 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o


  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Enum::get_hashcode(Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:
      _Enum_get_hashcode_m902175016 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o
      _Enum_GetHashCode_m2848082716 in Bulk_mscorlib_3.o


  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Enum::compare_value_to(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Enum::get_value(Il2CppObject*)", referenced from:

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::MonoType::get_Namespace(Il2CppReflectionType*)", referenced from:

  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Double::ParseImpl(char*, double*)", referenced from:
```

Comment: this is normal, and should not cause any issue. i think is dynamically loaded on the device. do you have any specific error or issues with it?

Comment: @JeanLuc i cant build the project in xcode, it give me a lot of unclear error and i believe that missing file is the main reason

Comment: Add the error messages to your question.

Comment: @JeanLuc i updated my question with the errors i got when i try to build an empty unity project for ios.

Comment: This seems to me like only a bottom part of the error message. Can you copy the errors with red exclamation marks in front.

Comment: how are your player settings configured? Scripting Backend (Mono or IL2CPP), Architectures (ARMv7, ARM64 or Universal)?